# Local RPM/YUM repository on Debian

Tags: centos, debian, yum, rpm

I manage a mix of Debian and CentOS servers.
I have a local DEB repository, kept up-to-date with apt-mirror, on a Debian server. Because this server has so much extra HD space, of 250GB at the moment, I would like to use it as a local RPM repository as well.

The only issue is how to do so. All of the local YUM repository info I have found is for working on an RPM distro. Are the tools available for Debian, would yum-utils and createrepo work, or will I have to create a new server with CentOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Debian will be fine** to run a mirror/repo.

This how to has what looks to be most of the instructions. Though a google search provides plenty of information on the topic too.

***Install your own local Repo server on CentOS 7***
https://deviantengineer.com/2016/03/repo-centos7/

The Debian package `createrepo` exists:
https://packages.debian.org/jessie/createrepo

```
apt-get install createrepo
```

And `yum-utils`: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/yum-utils

```
apt-get install yum-utils
```

Comment: FYI @Ryan Babchishin: The link is dead. If you can substitute for a new one please do so. Thanks.